# application /json get parameter from url

Tags: php, json

I am new with php ,

I want to get parameter from url ,

my request header is `application/json` ,

the chrome's network show Request URL

```
test/rdp3.php/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

and in fact it is

`test/rdp3.php/99`

PHP CODE

```
<?php
  $value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  echo $value->sessionName;
?>
```

how can I get url parameter(99) ?

I search it , but I can't find any information about that,

please help! thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you sure this is json encoded? Did you encode 99 or  something else?

Comment: I think it's `urlencode()`, and will output `[Object object]`

Comment: Wait... are you trying to read the variable from the URL with PHP or create a query string from some variables in PHP?

Comment: What makes you think that the URL is not what Chrome says the URL is?

Comment: I see the web page is test/rdp3.php/99, and I open the chrome's network whitch show the Request URL is test/rdp3.php/%5Bobject%20Object%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is `test/rdp3.php/99` is malformed.

What you would want to do is set a key and a value at the end of the url. So `test/rdp3.php/99` would be `test/rdp3.php?key=value`. The `?` denotes the beginning of the query string. Each key/value pair is then separated by `&`.

So you can have urls that look like this:

```
test/rdp3.php?key=value&id=99
```

Then in your PHP code to get the value of `key` you do:

```
$variableName = $_GET['key'];
```

To get the value of `id` you would do:

```
$variableName2 = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` will return `/99`. You could then use `trim()` or `substr()` to remove the `/`.

> ```
> 'PATH_INFO'
>     Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual script 
>     filename but preceding the query string, if available. For instance, if the 
>     current script was accessed via the URL 
>     http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar, then 
>     $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] would contain /some/stuff.
> ```

from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

**Update**

Based on your comment, I'm a bit confused on what you are attempting exactly. If you are getting [object Object] back that means that you tried to send a JavaScript object as part of the URI. I would suggest using the HTTP Request body for any json data. If you intend to use the URI to uniquely identify the data you are sending to the server (like '99'), then the code above will help you to parse the URI. If you are wondering how to parse an HTTP request payload, then the following code will help.

Example POST request using json from the command line:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"a": 1, "b": "abc"}' http://localhost:8080/test/rdp3.php/99
```

Using PHP to parse the json object:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_dump($data); // $data is of type stdClass so it can be treated like an object.
var_dump($data->a); // => 1
var_dump($data->b); // => abcd
```

Comment: but I get the "/[object Object]"

Comment: yes，the error is whitch I tried to send javascript object ,not like “99”,anyway ，thanks for your help